# How to access parent class members transparently from child class in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have following code:

```
    var Person = function () {
        this.Id = 0;
        this.Name = "";
    };

    var Emp = function () {
        this.OfficeEmail = "";
    };


    Emp.prototype = new Person();
    Emp.prototype.constructor = Emp; 

    var oEmp = new Emp();

    alert(oEmp.hasOwnProperty('OfficeEmail'));//true
    alert(oEmp.hasOwnProperty('Id'));//false
    alert(oEmp.hasOwnProperty('Name'));//false

    alert("Id" in oEmp); //true - inherited property
    alert("Name" in oEmp); //true - inherited property
    alert("OfficeEmail" in oEmp); //true - direct property

    //----------------The following screws up-------------------------
    oEmp.Id = 9999; //creates a new property in Emp instead of accessing from Person
    oEmp.Name = "Scott"; //creates a new property in Emp instead of accessing from Person
    oEmp.OfficeEmail = "Scott@yahoo.com";

    //Now the output is different here
    alert(oEmp.hasOwnProperty('OfficeEmail'));//true
    alert(oEmp.hasOwnProperty('Id'));//true - supposed to be false
    alert(oEmp.hasOwnProperty('Name'));//true - supposed to be false
```

While I understand that I can create another property (say "parent") and add it to "Emp" prototype (and access parent members using "parent"), I am just wondering if I can achieve transparent access to base class properties with just "childObject.parentProperty" notation (without creating any new "parent" property in child, to access parent members).

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you want, but you have access to any property that you prototype (I did'n know that they return false in hasOwnProperty), but in your example if you access oEmp.Id it will return 0 (your person Id).

Comment: In above case, if I access oEmp.Id (as last statement in above script), it does not return 0.  It returns 9999.